# Windows C++ Remove Cached Credentials

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, caching, credentials

We are having an interesting issue where we are using

```
WNetAddConnection2
```

to connect to a \\server\share with someone's credentials and map a drive. When we are done we call

```
WNetCancelConnection2
```

to close and cleanup the connection. We found a bug where if someone does this with credentials and then uses a connection without authentication we do something like this (no credentials):

```
FILE *file = _wfopen(L"\\\\server\\share\\file.txt", L"r");
```

I would not expect this to work since we cleaned up our connection but Windows seems to be caching it somewhere. I was wondering if there is anything else I can do in my code to clean up the connection from WNetAddConnection2 or manually remove the cached connection?

See code sample below...

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Winnetwk.h>
#include <string>

#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif
#pragma comment(lib, "mpr.lib")

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    NETRESOURCE nr;
    memset(&nr, 0, sizeof (NETRESOURCE));

    nr.dwType = RESOURCETYPE_ANY;
    nr.lpLocalName = L"L:";
    nr.lpRemoteName = L"\\\\server\\share";
    nr.lpProvider = NULL;

    DWORD ret = WNetAddConnection2(&nr, pswd, user, CONNECT_TEMPORARY);
    ret = WNetCancelConnection2(nr.lpLocalName, 0, TRUE);

    // I would not expect this to work since we closed the connection from above.
    FILE *file = _wfopen(L"\\\\server\\share\\file.txt", L"r");

    if (NULL != file)
    {
           // WHAT?!
    }
}
```

**Note**: This behavior is only observed on Windows Server 2008 R2 so far. On Windows 7 and XP this will fail saying "unknown user or bad password" (which is what we expect).
Also for some reason I don't see the credentials cache showing in the "Credential Manager" so I'm not really sure how the remote path is being authenticated or where the cached credentials are coming from.

**Update (More Notes)**:
If we do a reboot, the cached credentials are cleared. The software is long-running and rebooting the device would be extremely inconvenient for people. It almost looks like I need a way to clear the connection cache from the registry: "HKLM\SECURITY\Cache" ... That seems very hack-ish and I don't even know which cache entry is the one I want to clear (they are just listed as "NL$n", where n is 1-10. It would be nice to find a way to get rid of these credentials without reboot the whole system...

Comment: Perhaps a Kerberos ticket?  Try using [klist](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738673%28v=WS.10%29.aspx) to see if a ticket is present.

Comment: Any chance that [update 2871997](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/security/2871997) is installed on the server and not on the other machines, or vice versa?  It looks to be a fairly substantial change to the code handling credentials, so it might well have either fixed or introduced the problem you're seeing.

Comment: @Harry Johnston I used klist purge to clear everything. klist shows nothing and Credential Manager shows nothing.

Comment: Also the server does have the update you mentioned installed.

Comment: If you're in a position to experiment, consider uninstalling that update and seeing whether or not the problem persists.